# How to properly scale a square imageview into a rectangle imageview?

Tags: android

I am having some trouble trying to scale a square image (that is about 315dp x 315dp) to an image that should fill the width and have about 200dp height.

Basically what I am trying to do is to just properly preserve the aspect ratio of the image when it gets scaled to a more rectangular shape.  Any ideas? Here is what I've tried:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It should be like that
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <FrameLayout  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The FrameLayout is what fix your size of the Image, if you need any more help with you should read the Android UI manual